# Escaping rules when reading in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, escaping

Assume the file `text` is created as the following:

```
> cat > text
\abc
^D
```

The following two scripts generate different outputs and I don't understand why.

```
> s=$(cat text)
> echo $s
\abc
> cat text | while read line; do echo $line; done
abc
```

Why?

Comment: In addition to `read` interpreting (& removing) the backslash, you might also have trouble with `echo`, since some versions of it interpret escape sequences in the string. Also, since you use the variable `$line` without double-quotes, it'll be word-split and have any wildcards expanded into lists of matching filenames... which can cause really weird results. The reliable way to print a variable that may contain backslashes is `printf '%s\n' "$line"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`read` without the `-r` option interprets backslash escapes, and `\a` becomes `a`. See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read):

> `-r`
> If this option is given, backslash does not act as an escape
>   character. The backslash is considered to be part of the line. In
>   particular, a backslash-newline pair may not be used as a line
>   continuation.

Comment: I did it. Asked a question on SO before reading the fine manual. Although a part of me says that `-r` should have been the default behaviour. Many thanks for the answer.

Comment: @igor Yes, it should be the default! Also, the Bash man page is quite large and dense, so it's excusable not knowing it by heart. For Bash builtins, `help` is very useful: `help read` contains similar information.

Comment: This took me far longer to work out this morning than I'd appreciate!